# Sort elements to maximise amount of positive differences

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of integers. Numbers can be repeated. I would like "sort" them in that way to get as many "jumps" (difference from the very next element to the current one is positive) as possible.

Examples:

```py
[10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20]  # only one "jump" from 10 to 20
[10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20]  # three jumps (10->20, 10->20, 10->20) - the correct answer
[20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10]  # two jumps

[11, 16, 8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 17, 4, 15, 9, 11, 11, 7, 19, 16, 19, 5, 19, 11]  # 9
[9, 11, 2, 19, 4, 11, 15, 5, 7, 11, 16, 19, 1, 4, 8, 11, 16, 19, 9, 17]  # 14
[2, 9, 11, 16, 17, 19, 4, 5, 8, 15, 16, 9, 11, 1, 7, 11, 19, 4, 11, 19]  # 15
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 16, 17, 19, 4, 9, 11, 16, 19, 11, 19, 11]  # 16
```

My totally inefficient (but working) code.:

```py
def sol1(my_list):
    my_list.sort()
    final_list = []
    to_delete = []
    i = 0
    last_element = float('-inf')
    while my_list:
        if i >= len(my_list):
            i = 0
            for index in to_delete[::-1]:
                my_list.pop(index)
            if len(my_list):
                last_element = my_list.pop(0)
                final_list.append(last_element)
            to_delete = []
            continue

        curr_element = my_list[i]
        if curr_element > last_element:
            final_list.append(curr_element)
            last_element = curr_element
            to_delete.append(i)
        i += 1
    return final_list
```

Does anyone know a way to optimize the solution? For now I'm iterating the list many times. It doesn't need to be in Python.

Comment: Is this online for testing somewhere?

Comment: @KellyBundy no, you can generate any list and check (assert) if the answer is the same as mine. Mine is working, just slow. If you know any service I could provice quick test cases, share me.

Comment: For testing it would be convenient if the solution were in a function (with input and output being a list of ints).

Comment: And since this is about optimizing, it would be good to have code that generates realistic test cases (i.e., with as many elements and duplicates that you actually have).

Comment: @KellyBundy changed to a function. This is just a puzzle in my head so `[randint(1, 10**5) for i in range(10**4)]` is realistic test case.

Comment: I have no idea also if solution is unambiguous. The amount of jumps is for sure. Any list giving that amount is a correct one.

Comment: With your `[randint(1, 10**5) for i in range(10**4)]`, there are very few duplicates, and your solution is actually pretty fast. Unlike with my `list(range(n)) + [n] * n`, where it's quadratic runtime shows.

Comment: Hmm... you called your solution "totally inefficient" and said you're "iterating the list many times". But with your test case, you iterate it like *three* times (or six, if you count the deletion "iterations"). That doesn't seem like "many". Do I misunderstand something, or do you consider that "many", or is that test case not realistic after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be equivalent and only take O(n log n) time for sorting and O(n) time for the rest.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

arr = [11, 16, 8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 17, 4, 15, 9, 11, 11, 7, 19, 16, 19, 5, 19, 11]
d = OrderedDict(Counter(sorted(arr)))

ans = []
while d:
    ans += d
    for x in list(d):
        d[x] -= 1
        if not d[x]:
            del d[x]
print(ans)
```

Another, inspired by trincot:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

arr = [11, 16, 8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 17, 4, 15, 9, 11, 11, 7, 19, 16, 19, 5, 19, 11]

d = defaultdict(count)
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (next(d[x]), x))

print(arr)
```

Benchmarks along with other solutions, on your own suggested input and on two of mine (for each input, each solution's best three times from multiple attempts are shown):

```
[randint(1, 10**5) for i in range(10**4)]
 2.14 ms   2.15 ms   2.18 ms  Kelly4c
 2.19 ms   2.24 ms   2.32 ms  Kelly4b
 2.23 ms   2.25 ms   2.37 ms  Kelly4
 5.83 ms   6.02 ms   6.03 ms  original
 7.05 ms   7.12 ms   7.54 ms  Kelly1
 7.82 ms   8.43 ms   8.45 ms  Kelly3b
 8.13 ms   8.15 ms   8.92 ms  Kelly3
 9.06 ms   9.44 ms   9.50 ms  db0
10.25 ms  10.28 ms  10.31 ms  db
11.09 ms  11.11 ms  11.23 ms  trincot
11.19 ms  11.25 ms  11.58 ms  Kelly2
11.29 ms  11.65 ms  11.74 ms  db1
11.64 ms  11.65 ms  12.49 ms  Kelly3c

list(range(n := 1000)) + [n] * n
 0.57 ms   0.60 ms   0.63 ms  Kelly2
 0.64 ms   0.65 ms   0.68 ms  Kelly3
 0.66 ms   0.69 ms   0.69 ms  trincot
 0.69 ms   0.71 ms   0.71 ms  db
 0.69 ms   0.70 ms   0.70 ms  db1
 0.72 ms   0.74 ms   0.75 ms  Kelly3b
 0.99 ms   1.04 ms   1.11 ms  Kelly3c
 1.04 ms   1.08 ms   1.09 ms  Kelly1
28.27 ms  28.56 ms  28.63 ms  Kelly4b
36.58 ms  36.81 ms  37.03 ms  Kelly4c
39.78 ms  40.07 ms  40.37 ms  Kelly4
80.41 ms  80.96 ms  81.99 ms  original
81.00 ms  81.90 ms  82.08 ms  db0

list(range(n := 10000)) + [n] * n
 7.11 ms   7.37 ms   7.42 ms  Kelly2
 7.30 ms   7.62 ms   7.63 ms  db
 7.31 ms   7.31 ms   7.37 ms  Kelly3
 7.52 ms   7.64 ms   7.80 ms  trincot
 7.64 ms   7.82 ms   7.94 ms  db1
 8.81 ms   8.83 ms   8.84 ms  Kelly3b
10.18 ms  10.41 ms  10.52 ms  Kelly1
10.85 ms  10.92 ms  11.16 ms  Kelly3c
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVfNbtw2EL77KdhDsJQjL7S2AwRCN5f2VqB9AEEQtBJlE5YoheK2co08uzszJCVqvU7SJkWMNisN5@/7OEMNh0dz36ub94N@fm503zEjOyENk93Qa@PeLmil6ttWVEb2avTLv/RHZYSO2R@6FlrUv8rKxKwWTXlsTe1ePh6FdSBB1fR9O5tXaB6z6r6UKmZaDKJ0sXSparSwevgmUXO8PzZN69wd5AjpeB2pRvi5uIDg7DfRto87XmodpReM1WwfJshd1hwNRE1qUQR6JQDbsyyHx7/uZStYjdZW/nbPanppes0miMZaORpeR1YF/@psytnVnu1miWyY6g0tLGqkKlqSglALc9QKYwS5X69yD/jkRBklq/UWAfAH8bhvy@5Ql2xKGVdigrTAdxSziWD5CFoHEW7mCJXREMNzglK0gdea2MhyglwgZNiHO8G7cuJgtP2zbI9i5MAd4iBeYrulqOvIRUXY9w710plArWryR1GylIxmimBxWw6DUDWfgvyJbyqVLW5/gdVUHlrBrReAGqA7fG94NiEyWfJ7ieVfM@EcgZqLcMrGtzJR/bCNps4HJwPHhB1l8cmm@7YHgFCwyX9EeTuDnNsCPfVHQw3tYs99DUo2xaEfzdArcaLFWFuOaPo7rK27fjal7ia1n/bQeHN7Q0y7Wfgn2lEsSz7asu7CTPaY0bg/XmlbFKNom6JYGAHXizQAf/i/0dvMsomFh1hISSj3tOw9Lk@MJm5oLYW1KP8ysurzyL4BErqAMz2b01lhexXcatNXC2AQ7G/@1Ttq4fZa3klVtrx7LLDwXQu5twU5ZIZqJPUUMGb6Ar4owohFJOExmZEXsNoJhSZN20O3ba6kajbWo6XQhUrDj5dkH/asFeokq1ljjhHSJlUtiLo5qyxNr3YnX8AQ3dAPnKyiF1S/GvsMstBdEr3QXojzX5fQfq1/hlD/V/XKSAUjzSytjlq/TCOTeUjlSunDKvU1sJdphqbrNE8ICBXPw/Eu5eJHYhvYkcUV5ZKBrc06@JgeO3vuO1poOoGxhE5oGERG1HTHONYCjDnhmenNfRp1JtrcpkKPPhWXSDZlu3xpRfeh@VsO3DuKGQ1vuU80Wc1NJ586zA@kzk29pXzPD35YdyCM2M/20Tm1oB4wGTRe9Uq9vRMwjCF42N9kvangy2N@WG9hnT3MQ@PpKFgfdp9l/ukhZcmS0gjxUf3TDyHfaKmqHs5316rejTp2dq6I8WnxRIG5jBmIo5lbeIlZo8VH1PT7hy79bHGxOmqWWQVtcBHTaY6qog2194DYzdTu98b/HvxD5R5u/a9fuYUVfzLDTeaA/yf4D/h0eD16MRpb@xScGBhAw/jis58CAaOUlYBITAPeX/bL4Q8rWZr75kFPCJA8pq5DR7gI4CkOskCdKtAtwpfJevYlaPOwsiy9TvJotWDNgoVyHAVeulws785CAw34D6@FyPATilLmRsdVwr4Kg3nyOnFd5K5x3HI1b/4ZwHjeDo8QyWJ1MmTA3ky5vfmklhDUhSlyc1dthaJZMdpQgR2E3u88bHtT5IQhQzsYQs0p6a5KKZUYu31P@tjkDoRl75Jv3rzbXjesG9mGvWHcsEu2EzcReaMBOQiUpTd4L8NnmAZU2YmiiOZSgaqgOtpk7sLLoc52yeXlu@i03FF6G@Wb2GJyRFprGpytmsLRZpckSRSxt9CLOSSnvtrorBUp4lFjzdkVe1pa5PU2gsb5FEXPz/8A)):

```
from timeit import timeit
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict, defaultdict, deque
from itertools import count, chain, repeat
from random import randint, shuffle
from bisect import insort

def Kelly1(arr):
  d = OrderedDict(Counter(sorted(arr)))
  ans = []
  while d:
    ans += d
    for x in list(d):
        d[x] -= 1
        if not d[x]:
            del d[x]
  return ans

def Kelly2(arr):
  d = defaultdict(count)
  arr.sort(key=lambda x: (next(d[x]), x))
  return arr

def Kelly3(arr):
  ctr = Counter(arr)
  rounds = [[] for _ in range(max(ctr.values()))]
  for x, count in sorted(ctr.items()):
    for rnd in rounds[:count]:
      rnd.append(x)
  return list(chain.from_iterable(rounds))

def Kelly3b(arr):
  ctr = Counter(arr)
  rounds = [[] for _ in range(max(ctr.values()))]
  appends = [rnd.append for rnd in rounds]
  for x, count in sorted(ctr.items()):
    for append in appends[:count]:
      append(x)
  return list(chain.from_iterable(rounds))

def Kelly3c(arr):
  ctr = Counter(arr)
  rounds = [[] for _ in range(max(ctr.values()))]
  for x, count in sorted(ctr.items()):
    deque(map(list.append, rounds[:count], repeat(x)), 0)
  return list(chain.from_iterable(rounds))

def Kelly4(arr):
  arr.sort()
  out = [].append
  while arr:
    postpone = [].append
    last = None
    for x in arr:
      if last != x:
        out(x)
      else:
        postpone(x)
      last = x
    arr = postpone.__self__
  return out.__self__

def Kelly4b(arr):
  arr.sort()
  out = [].append
  while arr:
    postpone = [].append
    last = None
    arr = [x 
           for x in arr
           if last == x
           or out(last := x)]
  return out.__self__

def Kelly4c(arr):
  arr.sort()
  out = []
  while arr:
    postpone = [].append
    last = None
    out += [last := x 
            for x in arr
            if last != x
            or postpone(x)]
    arr = postpone.__self__
  return out

def original(my_list):
    my_list.sort()
    final_list = []
    to_delete = []
    i = 0
    last_element = float('-inf')
    while my_list:
        if i >= len(my_list):
            i = 0
            for index in to_delete[::-1]:
                my_list.pop(index)
            if len(my_list):
                last_element = my_list.pop(0)
                final_list.append(last_element)
            to_delete = []
            continue

        curr_element = my_list[i]
        if curr_element > last_element:
            final_list.append(curr_element)
            last_element = curr_element
            to_delete.append(i)
        i += 1
    return final_list

def db(arr):
  cumcount = []
  d = dict.fromkeys(arr, 0)
  for el in arr:
    cumcount.append(d[el])
    d[el] += 1
  return [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(cumcount, arr))]

def db0(arr):
  d = Counter(arr)
  keys = sorted(d.keys())
  ans = []
  while len(ans) < len(arr):
    for k in keys:
        if d.get(k, 0) > 0:
            ans.append(k)
            d[k] -= 1
  return ans

def db1(arr):
  cumcount = []
  d = {k: 0 for k in set(arr)}
  for el in arr:
    cumcount.append(d[el])
    d[el] += 1
  return [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(cumcount, arr))]

def trincot(lst):
  return [num for _,num in sorted(
    (i, num)
    for num, freq in Counter(lst).items()
        for i in range(freq)
  )]

funcs = [Kelly1, Kelly2, Kelly3, Kelly3b, Kelly3c, Kelly4, Kelly4b, Kelly4c, original, db, db0, db1, trincot]

def test(arr, funcs):
  print(arr)
  arr = eval(arr)

  expect = original(arr[:])
  for func in funcs:
    result = func(arr[:])
    if result != expect:
      print(expect[:20])
      print(result[:20])
    assert result == expect, func
  
  times = {func: [] for func in funcs}
  for _ in range(20):
    shuffle(funcs)
    for func in funcs:
      copy = arr[:]
      t = timeit(lambda: func(copy), 'gc.enable()', number=1)
      insort(times[func], t)
  for func in sorted(funcs, key=times.get):
    print(*('%5.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times[func][:3]), func.__name__)
  print()

test('[randint(1, 10**5) for i in range(10**4)]',
     funcs)
test('list(range(n := 1000)) + [n] * n',
     funcs)
test('list(range(n := 10000)) + [n] * n',
     list(set(funcs) - {original, Kelly4, Kelly4b, Kelly4c, db0}))
```

Comment: I made some benchmarking. It seems that version with Counter and OrderedDict is the fastest for now (~ two times from the rest). From testing I know now that the result (as list) is unambiguous (all ways gives the same result for any random list).

Comment: However the version "inspired by @trincot" is the shortest and quite easy to understand. Probably the best for my use case (talk about the puzzle with colleagues)

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Have you tried input like my `arr = list(range(n)) + [n] * n`?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Can you share your benchmarking code? I added my own to the answer now, and I don't get "~ two times from the rest" (regarding the solutions you saw when you commented). Though I'm using an "old" Python version there (some "pre-3.8"), that might make a difference and is the reason I'm keeping some more variations in my benchmark for now.

Comment: Here it is: https://ideone.com/mm6ipV
sol3 is ~2 times faster (0.25) than the rest (0.36, 0.36, 0.37, 0.47) in most typical case. For the worst case (`arr = list(range(n)) + [n] * n`) sol5 is better.

Comment: However... Why did you use OrderedDict? From Python 3.7 normal dicts are storing the order of inserting. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz Ah, you used a different input. I'll have a closer look later, also made some further improvements in the meantime that aren't included yet. Why OrderedDict? Not for it's orderedness but for how its orderedness is *implemented*. For fast iteration after deletions. If I'm not mistaken: 1) Normal dicts store entries in an array, so that deleted entries only get marked as deleted and iteration still sees them and has to ignore them. 2) OrderedDict has a doubly linked list, so that deleted entries are really gone and iteration doesn't waste time with them.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz (continuing) So with a normal dict (like if I just don't convert to OrderedDict but work with the Counter), my worst case input would take quadratic time since I'd have n iterations and each would take n+1 time. But with OrderedDict, it's linear time, because subsequent iterations don't have to re-iterate what previous iterations deleted. I had actually included the non-OrderedDict in the benchmark earlier and it was indeed much slower. But then I removed it because I had so many solutions already and it was strictly worse than with OrderedDict. I'll include it again.

Answer (score 1):

give each element `cumcount` based on how many times it has appeared before. then sort first by `cumcount` and then by its value.

```
arr = [11, 16, 8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 17, 4, 15, 9, 11, 11, 7, 19, 16, 19, 5, 19, 11]
cumcount = []
d = dict.fromkeys(arr, 0)

for el in arr:
    cumcount.append(d[el])
    d[el] += 1

[x[1] for x in sorted(zip(cumcount, arr))]
# [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 16, 17, 19, 4, 9, 11, 16, 19, 11, 19, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm should deal with duplicate values such that first all first occurrences of the numbers appear in sorted order, then the second occurrences of the duplicates in sorted order, then the third occurrences, ...etc.

```
from collections import Counter 

lst = [11, 16, 8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 17, 4, 15, 9, 11, 11, 7, 19, 16, 19, 5, 19, 11]

result = [num for _,num in sorted(
    (i, num)
    for num, freq in Counter(lst).items()
        for i in range(freq)
)]
```

`result` will be:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 15, 16, 17, 19, 4, 9, 11, 16, 19, 11, 19, 11]
```